# Insert a pdf/slide with hyperlinks in the body of an email

Tags: outlook, hyperlink

I would like to send an email with a slide/pdf containing hyperlinks in the body of the email.

In image formats I don't get the hyperlinks, and I cannot insert as pdf/slide except from an attachment.

Could you please advise on that?
Thank you